# get current controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, front-controller

in a function I want to reach current controller:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
```

this only gives a handler but not current controller.

I changed the code from function to inside of controller.
and asked their origins both  the handler I got from getInstance and this

```
var_dump(get_class($front), get_class($this));
```

I get:

```
string 'Zend_Controller_Front' (length=21)
string 'IndexController' (length=15)
```

How can I reach real initiated front controller?

I cant pass as a parameter, because this function is used trillion times.

Comment: for quicness I defined a global variable, in IndexController init I set it with $this.

Comment: Getting an instance of an action controller is generally not a great idea. If you need code that resides in your action controller available elsewhere in your application or library, that code should likely be in your library to begin with.  The second answer by takeshin also states this.

Comment: I need a variable defined in controller in a function that makes links.(href) Should I bind this function to a class?

Comment: Any method in controller which is not an action should be probably marked as *protected*. Protected method in controllers are generally a sign, you should separate them in [action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
```

Comment: it returns 
string 'index' (length=5) 
I want to get instance!

Answer (score 1):

Possible with:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
$request = $front->getRequest();
$module = ucfirst($request->getModuleName());
$controller = ucfirst($request->getControllerName());

$instance = new $module . '_' . $controller . 'Controller';
```

In Action Helper:

```
$instance = $this->getActionController();
```

**But**, this probably means that's something wrong with your architecture.
You should move the common code you need to action helper, service or model.

Comment: Of course, the first approach produces a second instance of the controller class, not the instance created within the dispatch loop. Right? In any case, as you note, needing a reference to the controller instance itself is probably indicative of some architecture issue.