# Automatically inject resources into controller

Tags: zend-framework, dependency-injection

I'm trying to implement dependency injection in our Zend Framework project.

In previous APS.NET based projects we've used [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) and overwritten the  `DefaultControllerFactory` to inject the dependencies into the controllers.

I'm not sure where to do the injection in Zend Framework? I've looked into `Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract` and `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract` but none of them seems to enable me to inject into the currently instantiated controller.

I would love to be able to inject into the constructor of the current controller like i do in ASP.NET, but setters are acceptable (I guess).

Any ideas as to how to accomplish this or something similar?

Ultimately i would like to be able to do something like this:

```
MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  // private vars
  [...]

  public function __constructor($authenticationService, $userRepository) {
    $this->_authServ = $authenticationService;
    $this->_userRepo = $userRepository;
  }    

}
```

I would like to do something like i do for stuctureMap:

```
For(authenticationService).Use(WhatEverClass);
```

or maybe:

```
$currentController->authServ = $authenticationService;
$currentController->userRepo = $userRepository;
```

**In short: Where can we intercept the creation of (or get the instance of) the current controller?**

Similar (unanswered) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345414/get-current-controller)

Thanks!
/Jon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zend Framework lead developer Matthew Weier O'Phinney has a post that seems to address the idea of injecting resources into controllers:

[A Simple Resource Injector for ZF Action Controllers](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/235-A-Simple-Resource-Injector-for-ZF-Action-Controllers.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is very similar to what i was looking for, very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Check out also [PHP-DI](http://mnapoli.github.com/PHP-DI/), this is a dependency injection library that integrates with Zend Framework. It works with annotations.

It enables you to do things like:

```
MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    /**
     * @Inject
     * @var MyService
     */
    private $myService;

    public function helloAction() {
        return $this->myService->sayHello();
    }
}
```